# Setting generic type only in one class

Tags: c#, generics

I have two generic classes:

```
public class First<T>
{
    ...
}
public class Second<T>
{
    ...
}
```

I use Second class as parameter for First class constructor:

```
var instance = new First<int>(new Second<int>());
```

Is it possible to specify generic type (integer in my example) only for First class constructor like this:

```
var instance = new First<int>(new Second());
```

?

Comment: If Second were an inner class of First. But then you would need to type new First<int>.Second()

Comment: You'd need to show the constructor for `First<T>` to be certain it's even _possible_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe type inference for generic constructor arguments is being added to C# 6. Right now, the answer is no.

Answer (score 4):

This is my workaround suggestion, which gives you a nice syntax.

```
public class First
{
    public static First<T> Create<T>(Second<T> second)
    {
        return new First<T>(second);
    }
}

public class First<T>
{
    public First(Second<T> second)
    {

    }
}
public class Second<T>
{

}
```

Use it like this:

```
var instance = First.Create(new Second<int>());
```

Comment: This is a clever solution, but does the static method need a different class? You could just put it into the generic class, but call it without a type argument. Might have to change T to some other letter in the static method's signature though.

Comment: You have to write `First<int>.Create(new Second<int>());` to access the static method `Create` when the method is in the `First<T>` class.

Answer (score 1):

This is a trick that could work: (Whether or not it is good practice, I'll leave to you)

```
public class Second { }
```

Inside the `Second<T>` class:

```
public static implicit operator Second<T>(Second second) {
    return new Second<T>();
}
```

This will only work if the `First<T>` constructor ONLY accepts `Second<T>` and not another `Second<U>` or something.